# Can mutator methods be applied to objects in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, mutation

I'm having some trouble with my java program and I'm not sure if this is the problem but would calling a mutator method on an object inside an araylist work as intended?

For example

```
public class Account
{
    private int balance = 0;

    public Account(){}

    public void setAmount(int amt)
    {
         balance = amt;
    }
}


public class Bank
{
    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    public staic void main(String[] args)
    {
        accounts.add(new Account());
        accounts.add(new Account());
        accounts.add(new Account());

        accounts.get(0).setAmount(50);
    }
}
```

Would this work as intended or is there something that would cause this not to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Is the problem but would calling a mutator method on an object inside an ArrayList work as intended?***

Yes, if your intention is to update the first account in the list. **Keep in mind that the array list doesn't store objects, but *references* to objects.** Mutating one of the objects won't change the reference stored in the list.

The first account will be updated, and when referencing `accounts.get(0)` again it will show the updated balance.

Here's an [**ideone.com demo**](http://ideone.com/D0P28) demonstrating it. (I've just fixed a few minor typos such as adding `static` in front of the `accounts` declaration.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++)
    System.out.println("Balance of account " + i + ": " +
                       accounts.get(i).balance);
```

yields

```
Balance of account 0: 50
Balance of account 1: 0
Balance of account 2: 0
```

which hopefully is what you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should work as intended.  It is no different than:

```
Account firstAccount = accounts.get(0);
firstAccount.setAmount(50);
```

Remember, `ArrayList`'s `get()` method returns the actual object stored in the `ArrayList`, not a copy of it.